# virtual host wamp laravel not working "If Your Business Had Hands,"

Tags: php, laravel, apache, wamp

i'm trying to create virtual host ecommerce.com instead of php artisan serve, but too bad it direct to commerce.com site, knowing that I modify file `D: \ wamp \ bin \ apache \ apache2.4.39 \ conf \ extra \ httpd-vhosts.conf` and `C: \ Windows \ System32 \ Drivers \ etc \ host`.

**host file**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ecommerce.com
::1 localhost
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ecommerce.com
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ecomm/public"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you restarted WAMP after making changes?

Comment: @Tpojka thx for answer ,but  i already restart wamp

Comment: Do you have anything else in `www` directory? Maybe there is an conflict because `www` itself is the virtual host location.

Comment: @Tpojka yeh i have a lot project

Comment: Try to create directory outside/next to `www` and point virtual host location to it.

Comment: Have you tried creating the virtual host from the wamp panel?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei thx for answer ,i dont know i just edit this files hosts and httpd-vhosts.conf

Answer (score 0):

When you use WAMP, you can create virtual hosts from the Wamp panel. In your browser go to localhost and in the wamp page find `create virtual host` (or something like this).

I think it's better to undo the changes you've made manually first.